# How to see that Eisenstein series are eigenfunctions of the laplacian?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms

Let $\Gamma$ be a discrete subgroup of $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ of finite type. Let $c_1,\ldots,c_h\in\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ be a set of representatives of the $\Gamma$-equivalence classes of cusps. For each $i$, let $\sigma_i\in PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ send $\infty$ to $c_i$. Then the Eisenstein series for the cusp $c_i$ is defined by
$$E_{c_i}(z,s) = \sum_{\sigma\in\Gamma_{c_i}\setminus\Gamma}\frac{y^s}{|cz+d|^{2s}}$$
where $z = x+iy$, and $\sigma$ is represented by the matrix $\left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array}\right)$.

In many sources, it is claimed that any such Eisenstein series is an eigenfunction of the Laplacian $D := y^2\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial y^2}\right)$, with eigenvalue $s(s-1)$. In fact, I've checked, via mathematica, that this is true for each of the summands defining $E_{c_i}(z,s)$. However, this is not very enlightening.

As an algebraic geometer with some very basic familiarity with modular forms via Diamond-Shurman's book, my very naive questions are:

1. Directing computing the Laplacian applied to the summands is very tedious. Is there a slick, preferably elementary, way to show that these are eigenfunctions?
2. How can one piece together the fact that these summands are $D$-eigenfunctions using the general machinery of the representation theory of Lie groups?
3. How did people first discover/realize that such Eisenstein series are eigenfunctions of the Laplacian?
4. I understand that this is a very basic question, and probably covered in many places. However, the handful of references I've looked at all seem to omit a proof of this fact. What are some good references for this?

Answer (score 6):

Here's an answer to Question 1 that reduces the result to checking that
$D$ is invariant under hyperbolic isometries $z \mapsto (az+b)/(cz+d)$
plus a couple of elementary identities.  I'll let others answer questions
2 (which now amounts to a Lie-theoretic picture of the invariance of $D$),
3 (history), and 4 (references).

First check it for $c=0$, when $y^s/\left|cz+d\right|^{2s}$ simplifies to
$d^{-2s} y^s$ which is clearly multiplied by $s(s-1)$ when we apply $D$:
the $\partial^2/\partial x^2$ term vanishes,
and $\partial^2/\partial y^2$ takes $y^s$ to $s(s-1) y^{s-2}$.

Then use the fact that $D$, being the hyperbolic Laplacian,
is invariant under the action of ${\rm PSL}_2({\bf R})$
on the hyperbolic plane by fractional linear transformations.
It is a standard calculation that for real $a,b,c,d$
the imaginary part of $(az+b)/(cz+d)$ is
$(ad-bc) \, {\rm Im}(y) / \left| cz+d \right|^2$
(which in turn follows from the identity
$$
\frac{az+b}{cz+d} - \frac{az'+b}{cz'+d} = \frac{ad-bc}{(cz+d)(cz'+d)}
$$
by taking $z' = \bar z$).  Thus $({a\;b\atop c\;d})$ takes
$y^s$ to $y^s / \left| cz+d \right|^{2s}$;
since $y^s$ is an $s(s-1)$-eigenfunction for $D$,
so is $y^s / \left| cz+d \right|^{2s}$.  $\Box$